# How to use ansible openstack modules with a ssh socks proxy

Tags: proxy, ansible, socks

OpenSSH allows to act as an encrypted tunnel with a socks proxy. This can be used for openstack modules in ansible. However the ansible documentation doesn't mention how to use any other proxy than HTTP/HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## socks proxy

First configure [OpenSSH socks tunnel](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#DynamicForward):

Add in `~/.ssh/config` something like:

```
# Physical host
Host Dell-em1
    User myuser
    HostName 192.168.x.x
    ForwardAgent yes

Host undercloud-0
    User stack
    HostName undercloud-0
    ProxyJump Dell-em1
    IdentityFile /home/mvutcovi/infrared/.workspaces/workspace_2018-02-14_18-24-58/id_rsa

Host controller-0
    User heat-admin
    HostName 192.168.24.13
    ProxyJump Dell-em1
    IdentityFile /home/mvutcovi/infrared/.workspaces/workspace_2018-02-14_18-24-58/id_rsa
    DynamicForward localhost:65432
```

Now test that you can access the Horizon dashboard with:

```
ALL_PROXY=socks5h://localhost:65432 curl -vi 10.0.0.107:80/dashboard
```

## openstack client config - [clouds.yml](https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/configuration/index.html#clouds-yaml)

Create `~/clouds.yaml` file with the following content:

```
clouds:
  my_cloud:
    auth:
      auth_url: http://10.0.0.107:5000/v2.0
      project_name: myproject
      username: admin
      password: XXXXXX
    region_name: ""
```

Test with:

```
ALL_PROXY="socks5h://localhost:65432" openstack --os-cloud my_cloud server list
```

## ansible

Create an openstack_test.yaml file with the following content:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Upload CentOS7 iso image
      os_image:
        name: centos7
        cloud: "my_cloud"
        container_format: bare
        disk_format: iso
        filename: /path_to_local_file/CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1708.iso
        properties:
          cpu_arch: x86_64
          distro: redhat
      environment:
        ALL_PROXY: "socks5h://localhost:65432"
      when: false
# vim:et:sw=2:ts=2:sts=2:
```

The environment variable `ALL_PROXY` needs to be set to `socks5h://localhost:65432`. This variable is used by libcurl which is used by most ansible modules that are connecting to remote http services. For more details see: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-env.html and https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SOCKS_PROXY.html